# Append on :nth child using loop

Tags: jquery

my problem is that how can I append the first info on the first tr that I appended and so on..

here's my code

```
$('.table').append('<tbody>');
    console.log(tableBody.length);

    //count tbody tbody_tr
    var tbody_tr = tableBody.length / unique_header.length;

    //count how many column / row 
    var tbody_td = tableBody.length / tbody_tr;

    console.log('every td' + tbody_td + 'body tr' + tbody_tr);
    for(appendCountBody = 0; appendCountBody < tbody_tr; appendCountBody++){

        $('.table tbody').append('<tr>');

        $('.table tbody').append('</tr>');

    }

    //tbody tr td
    var counter = 0;
    for(appendCountBodyTd = 0; appendCountBodyTd < tableBody.length; appendCountBodyTd++){

        if(counter < tbody_td){
            console.log(counter + ':' + tbody_td+ ':' + tableBody[appendCountBodyTd] );
            $('.table tbody tr').append('<td>'+tableBody[appendCountBodyTd]+'</td>');
            counter = counter + 1;
        }else{
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

$('.table').append('</tbody>');
```

here's an image of the info and how it looks like in my browser

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the first info?

Comment: @jason the first info is `1` `john` `doe` and on second row `2` `ralph` `garcia`

Comment: So is that "info" in an object and you want to put it in those elements as you create them with jQuery?

Comment: @Jason it is on an array format..... it is actually called via ajax... I'm trying to create a dropdown which has a table format for values

Comment: @Jason I was able to get how many row will be displayed according to the data... but I wasn't able to solve how to put the first info `1` `john` `doe` on the first `<tr>` and so on.

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: @Jason no sir..... the first loop will get how many row will be displayed and the second loop there is for how many columns display per row...

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you make some HTML from scratch to show how you want that sample data arranged in a table and add the HTML to your question?

Comment: @Jason here an example of the table....http://jsfiddle.net/aqm7kjbg/18/

as you can see in my code.. you cannot use nested loop... since the first loop will get how many row displayed and the second loop will display the data on that row... if I use nested loop, the loop will repeat the first info over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to fix the `$("table")` selector to match your DOM, but here's the basic idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var testData = [
        "1", "John", "Doe",
        "2", "Ralph", "Garcia",
        "3", "John", "Jean"
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < testData.length; i+= 3) {
        $("table").append(
            $("<tr>")
                .append(
                    $("<td>").html(testData[i + 0]),
                    $("<td>").html(testData[i + 1]),
                    $("<td>").html(testData[i + 2])
                )
        );
    }
});
```

If the length of each "record" in your incoming list might vary, you can use something more flexible like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var testData = [
        "1", "John", "Doe", "alpha",
        "2", "Ralph", "Garcia", "beta",
        "3", "John", "Jean", "gamma"
    ];

    var recordLength = 4;

    for(var i = 0; i < testData.length; i += recordLength) {
        $newRow = $("<tr>");
        for(var j = 0; j < recordLength; j++) {
            $newRow.append(
                $("<td>").html(testData[i + j])
            );
        }

        $("table").append($newRow);
    }
});
```

Ideally, though, the data should be packaged better on the other end so that it comes in as an array of arrays or an array of objects. Here is an example with an array of arrays (with varying length):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var testData = [
        ["1", "John", "Doe", "alpha", "beta"],
        ["2", "Ralph", "Garcia", "gamma"],
        ["3", "John", "Jean", "delta", "epsilon"]
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
        $newRow = $("<tr>");
        for(var j = 0; j < testData[i].length; j++) {
            $newRow.append(
                $("<td>").html(testData[i][j])
            );
        }
        $("table").append($newRow);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry my mistake.... I miss something... thanks for helping... you are a great help

Comment: Can I ask you a question sir? is there a way for me to loop the `$("<td>").html(testData[i + 2])` depending on my data?

Comment: Do you mean if the length of each person's record might sometimes be different than the 3 values (id, first name and last name) that it is right now? By the way, do you have control over how the data is packaged that you're getting with AJAX?

Comment: yes it is not fixed value and I have a control... I'm using php(pdo).... so if I do a select query selecting all it'll have more than 3 values.....

Comment: I added a couple more options. I'm going to bed. If you have any more questions, be as descriptive as possible and I'll answer them when I wake up.

Comment: If you need help packaging the data with your PHP, add the PHP you have now to your question and I'll check it out in the morning. Otherwise, glad I could help!